# HTTPS proxy server with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, https, proxy

I am trying to create a HTTPS proxy server with python3. I want to use this proxy server for a school project. The code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import urllib.request
import ssl
import shutil
import os

#Key/cert generated with:
#openssl req -nodes -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj /CN=localhost

class Test(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200, "ok")
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS')
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
        self.end_headers()

    def do_CONNECT(self):
        print(self.protocol_version)
        self.wfile.write(f"{self.protocol_version} 200 Connection established\r\n".encode('utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write(("Proxy-agent: %s\r\n" % self.version_string()).encode('utf-8'))
        self.wfile.write("\r\n".encode('utf-8'))
     
    def do_GET(self):
        print("Getting")
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        with urllib.request.urlopen(self.path) as url:
            self.copyfile(url, self.wfile)


def main():
    port = 4443
    host = 'localhost'
    sslctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    sslctx.check_hostname = False
    sslctx.load_cert_chain("./cert.pem", keyfile='key.pem')

    httpd = HTTPServer((host, port), Test)
    httpd.socket = sslctx.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
    print(f"Server running on {host}:{port}")
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code works when using: `https://localhost:4443/https://google.com`
with the adjustment of:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(self.path[1:]) as url:
            self.copyfile(url, self.wfile)
```

However I want to be able to use this HTTPS proxy while setting it up in a browser like Firefox. The Firefox settings here:
[image]

I also added the cert.pem file to firefox to be a thrusted authority. When the proxy is running and the proxy is enabled in Firefox i get the following message:

[image]

How can I solve this?